# comparing with date values with if condition

Tags: powerbi, data-science, dax, business-intelligence, msbi

I want to compare workers present status with time,

if any worker comes 10 mins Late then it should be like "Below 10 mins"(I tried to derive it from time diff column which I done with help of IN time & Report time )

```
"IF('Attendance Info'[Time Diff] <= "00:30","Below 10 mins","others")"
```

and the error is:

> DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Date
>   with values of type Text. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function
>   to convert one of the values.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is. You're comparing a date `[Time Diff]` with text `"00:30"`. They probably both should be time data types.

Comment: yeah but the time diff data type is date data type and it's format is HH:MM, when i want to change data types and am getting error records in answers.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast google search would have get you the following results:

In DAX:

```
Column = IF('Table'[Column1] <= TIMEVALUE("00:30");"Below10";"Others")
```

In M:

```
= if [Column1] <= Time.FromText("00:30") then "Bleow10" else "Others"
```

Comment: thanks for response, i tried following one u mentioned above  
Column = IF('Table'[Column1] <= TIMEVALUE("00:30");"Below10";"Others")
actually the code worked but it's showing everything not particularly 30 mins.(the Time diff data type is date data type and it's format is HH:MM)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Then just make sure that `'Table'[Column1]` is also a `Time` format. `Column = IF(TIMEVALUE('Table'[Column1]) <= TIMEVALUE("00:30");"Below10";"Others")`. And check if the `<=` is right, I just assumed the direction.

Comment: No problem. Dont forget to accept it as answer, for future people who have the same problem.